# Overriding save() method on form, how do I redirect to or show the form again after raiseError or enqueueMessage?

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, form, error-handling

I am developing a component that uses a standard list/edit form to create records in the database (all of which goes smoothly) based on the Hello World! tutorial [here](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Introduction).

In addition to saving info to the database, however, I need to make a call to an external API and send out a couple of confirmation emails (which I will tackle later and probably come back here to ask about).

In my controller for the item (rather than the list), I have created my own save() method in which I add some data and change some other data. This is where I would make the call to my external API and get some sort of response.

**In *controllers/authorization.php*:**

```
public function save($key = null, $urlVar = null)
{
    if (isset($_POST['jform'])) {
        // Get the original POST data
        $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;

        $original = $jinput->post->get('jform', array(), 'array');

        // Trim each of the fields
        foreach($original as $key=>$value) {
            $postData[$key] = trim($value);
        }

        // Set value of authorization date
        $postData['authDate'] = $this->prepareInputDate(time());

        // Create transaction ID based on date and time
        $postData['merchantTransId'] .= date('YmdHis', time());

        // Strip phone number of all but numeric digits
        $postData['phone'] = $this->prepareInputNumeric($original['phone']);

        // Make call to external API
        $response = $this->callApi($postData);

        // If bad response from external API, throw error
        if (!$response) {
            JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage('There was an error with the API', 'error');
            return false;
        }

        // Only store last 4 digits of account number
        $postData['accountNo'] = substr($postData['accountNo'], -4);

        // Save everything back to the $_POST global variable
        $jinput->post->set('jform', $postData);
    }

    // Finally, save the processed form data
    return parent::save('id', $urlVar);
}
```

What I am having a problem with is when throwing the error, I lose my form and all the data that was entered into it. In most cases, when the external API returns a bad response, it will be due to a badly formed parameter that can easily be fixed and resubmitted (e.g. invalid credentials or invalid characters in the fullName field).

**I would like to be able to display an informative error message on screen either while still showing the populated form on screen or after redirecting back to the populated form.**

**Can this be done from within the save() method or is there some method that is called after form validation but before save() where I can make the API call?**

Three days ago, when I started this project, I knew absolutely nothing about Joomla development. Everything I have been able to do so far has been learned from the tutorial I mentioned above or from Google searches. So if there is any code that I should have included but didn't, just let me know what I should show and I'll edit my question to include it.

Answer (score 3):

You should use a session to save the form data. In the CMS there is a special User State for this. Just before you return false you should save the current data into the user state:

```
// Save the form data in the session
JFactory::getApplication()->setUserState($this->option . '.edit.authorization.data', $postData);
```

`$this->option` here is the name of your component.

Then in the model you can retrieve it in your `loadFormData()` method:

```
// Check the session for previously entered form data
$data = JFactory::getApplication()->getUserState($this->option . '.edit.authorization.data', array());

if (empty($data))
{
    $data = $this->getItem();
}
```

If you have a success in your controller then you should flush the data from the session before return:

```
JFactory::getApplication()->setUserState($this->option . '.edit.authorization.data', null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are saving your form data too late. If there is an error, it returns `false` before it could save data. And you should save `$original` data, not already manipulated data.

```
// If bad response from external API, throw error
if (!$response) {
    // Save everything back to the $_POST global variable
    $jinput->post->set('jform', $original);

    JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage('There was an error with the API', 'error');
    return false;
}
```